# K Means Clustering - Handling Non-Numerical Data

Tags: python, k-means

I have twitter data that I want to cluster. It is text data and I learned that K means can not handle Non-Numerical data. I wanted to cluster data just on the basis of the tweets. The data looks like this.

[image]

I found this code that can converts the text into numerical data.

```
def handle_non_numerical_data(df):
    columns = df.columns.values

    for column in columns:
        text_digit_vals = {}
        def convert_to_int(val):
            return text_digit_vals[val]

        if df[column].dtype != np.int64 and df[column].dtype != np.float64:
            column_contents = df[column].values.tolist()
            unique_elements = set(column_contents)
            x = 0
            for unique in unique_elements:
                if unique not in text_digit_vals:
                    text_digit_vals[unique] = x
                    x += 1

            df[column] = list(map(convert_to_int, df[column]))

    return df

df  = handle_non_numerical_data(data)
print(df.head())
```

output

```
   label  tweet
0      9     24
1      5     11
2     17     45
3     14    138
4     18    112
```

I'm quite new to this and I don't think this is what I need to fit the data. What is a better way to handle Non-Numerical data (text) of this nature?

Edit: When running K means clustering Algorithm on raw text data I get this error.

**ValueError: could not convert string to float**

Comment: what do you mean by "handle non-numerical data"? this can mean a lot of things

Comment: By Non-Numerical Data I mean Text Data.

Comment: i mean by "handle". you mean vectorization of some sort? you should specify what you expect the transformation to be

Comment: I didn't mention because I am pretty much walking in the dark here but yes maybe I need to Vectorize my data. I also read somewhere that I should create One-Hot Encoding for the data. Anyways can you point me to some tutorial for Vectorization?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most typical way of handling non-numerical data is to convert a single column into multiple binary columns. This is called "getting dummy variables" or a "one hot encoding" (among many other snobby terms).

There are other things you can do to translate the data to numbers, such as [sentiment analysis](https://www.datacamp.com/community/tutorials/simplifying-sentiment-analysis-python) (i.e. cetagorize each tweet into happy, sad, funny, angry, etc...), analyzing the tweets to determine if they are about a certain subject or not (i.e. Does this tweet talk about a virus?), the number of words in each tweet, the number of spaces per tweet, if it has good grammar or not, etc. As you can see, you are asking about a very broad subject.

When transforming data to binary columns, you get the number of unique values in your column and make that many new columns, each one of them filled with zeros and ones.

Let's focus on your first column:

```py
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'account':['realdonaldtrump','naredramodi','pontifex','pmoindia','potus']})

    account
0   realdonaldtrump
1   narendramodi
2   pontifex
3   pmoindia
4   potus
```

This is equivalent to:

```py
pd.get_dummies(df, columns=['account'], prefix='account')

   account_naredramodi  account_pmoindia  account_pontifex  account_potus  \
0                    0                 0                 0              0   
1                    1                 0                 0              0   
2                    0                 0                 1              0   
3                    0                 1                 0              0   
4                    0                 0                 0              1   

   account_realdonaldtrump  
0                        1  
1                        0  
2                        0  
3                        0  
4                        0
```

This is one of many methods. You can check out this article about [one hot encoding here](https://machinelearningmastery.com/how-to-one-hot-encode-sequence-data-in-python/).

**NOTE**: When you have many unique values, doing this will give you many columns and some algorithms will crash due to not having enough degrees of freedom (too many variables, not enough observations). Last, if you are running a regression, you will run into perfect multicollinearity if you do not drop one of the columns.

Going back to your example, if you want to turn all your columns into this kind of data, try:

```
pd.get_dummies(df)
```

However, I wouldn't do this for the `tweet` column because each tweet is its own unique value.

Comment: Do I do the same for the tweets column as well? Because I want to cluster on the tweets column

Comment: I wouldn't do that because I doubt you have any duplicate tweets. I edited the answer slightly in hopes of pushing you in the right direction. There are many ways to handle this and none of them is considered the standard method. You have a lot of preprocessing to do.

Answer (score 0):

As k-means is a method of vector quantization, you should vectorize your textual data in one way or another.

See some examples of using k-means over text:
[Word2Vec](https://ai.intelligentonlinetools.com/ml/k-means-clustering-example-word2vec/)
[tf-idf](https://medium.com/@MSalnikov/text-clustering-with-k-means-and-tf-idf-f099bcf95183)